# Android. При ошибке 500, выводить уведомление

Tags: android, android-toast

Как можно ловить ошибку 500 и выводить уведомление (Toast).

API

```
@POST("events/")
Call<Event> createEvent(@Body Event event);
```

RestClient

```
public void createEvent(final String eventId) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    Event event = realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("id", eventId).findFirst();
    event = realm.copyFromRealm(event);
    realm.close();

    if (event != null) {
        ArrayList<String> interest_ids = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Interest interest: event.getInterests()
                ) {
            interest_ids.add(interest.getId());
        }
        event.setInterestIds(interest_ids);
        happApi.createEvent(event).enqueue(new Callback<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Event> call, Response<Event> response) {

                Log.d("HAPP_API", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                Log.d("HAPP_API", response.message());

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    Event event = response.body();

                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    realm.beginTransaction();

                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(event);

                    realm.commitTransaction();
                    realm.close();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(BroadcastIntents.EVENTEDIT_REQUEST_OK);
                    intent.putExtra("event_id", event.getId());
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BroadcastIntents.EVENTEDIT_REQUEST_FAIL);
                    intent.putExtra("CODE", response.code());
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", response.message());
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }

                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                Event oldEvent = realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("id", eventId).findFirst();
                oldEvent.deleteFromRealm();
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.close();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Event> call, Throwable t) {

                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                Event oldEvent = realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("id", eventId).findFirst();
                oldEvent.deleteFromRealm();
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.close();

                Intent intent = new Intent(BroadcastIntents.EVENTEDIT_REQUEST_FAIL);
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

ApiService

```
public static void createEvent(String eventId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(App.getContext(), APIService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_PATCH_EVENTCREATE);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EE_ID, eventId);
    App.getContext().startService(intent);
}
```

Comment: `if(errorCode == 500){Toast.makeText(context, "шота сламалась, туту ашыпка 500!!!111адын").show()}`

Comment: Что именно у вас не получилось, пока вы пробовали решить эту проблему самостоятельно?

Comment: @metalurgus я вообще не понимал как правильно исправлять данную проблему. Не нашел источников. Решил задать здесь, вдруг тут дадут дельное решение) И почему мои вопросы всегда минусуют?

Comment: Потому, что вы даже не утруждаетесь описать, что такое "ошибка 500". Это ошибка подклучения Bluetooth, или такой код у ошибки OutOfMemory? Вот и получается, что вопрос ваш крайне низкого качества, что и отражается в его рейтинге.

Comment: Неужели вы показали код? Ок, теперь попробуем выяснить, что же все-таки не получается. Вы знаете, как определить, какой код пришел в ответ?

Comment: @metalurgus Да. Мне просто надо, проверять данную строчку `APIService.createEvent(event.getId())` возвращает она КОД 200 OK или 500 ( Ошибка сервера)

Comment: @metalurgus мне надо ловить в логах данную строчку, `500 Internal Server Error http://192.168.11.175:8000/api/v1/events/ `

Comment: в `onResponse` `response.code()` вернет вам код. Проверьте, равняется ли он 500, и покажите тост, если равнется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(response.code() == 500) {
  Toast.makeText(context, "шота сламалась, туту ашыпка 500!!!111адын", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Если `onResponse()` выполнется не в UI потоке, то надо показ тоста обернуть, например, в `Handler`

Answer (score 4):

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

if (connection.getResponseCode() == 500){
    //тут кидаете тост
}
```

Comment: А вот у меня есть функция в которой делается запрос `APIService.createEvent(event.getId());` Как его можно проверить?

Comment: Мне эта строчка ни о чем не говорит!

Comment: Вы бы все таки добавили немного кода в вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, щас добавлю.

Comment: Я затрудняюсь ответить, так как не знаком с  реализацией классов которые вы используете для запросов. Но думаю стоит обратить внимание на строчку                 Log.d("HAPP_API", String.valueOf(response.code()));  , что она вам возвращает?